# javascript - remember user data after loggin in and checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, authentication

I'm helping developing improvements on a client website. In one of those improvements, there is the Login form. I want to add a checkbox that when the user logs in after selecting this checkbox, it remember his login data.

The login form I have:

```
<form id='formLogin' method='post' name='formLogin'> <!-- action="telaInicial"> -->
        <label for="usuario">{label_index_user}</label><input name="usuario" id="usuario" type="text" /><br />
        <label for="senha">{label_index_password}</label><input name="senha" id="senha" type="password" maxlength="8" /><br />
        <div id="btLogin"><input type='button' id='entrar' value="{label_index_enviar}"/></div>
        <div id="btLogout"><input type='button' id='deslogar' value="{label_index_sair}"/></div>
        <br><div id="checkLembraDados"><input type='checkbox' id='lembrar' />{label_index_lembrardados}</div>
        <a id="esqueciSenha" href='#' >{label_index_esquecisenha}</a>
    </form>
```

So I think I need to put on my JS file something like:

```
$("#lembrar").click(function() {
        if document.getElementById("lembrar").checked = true {
            // CODE FOR REMEMBERING DATA FOR FUTURE LOGINS
        }
    });
```

I don't know if I made myself clear on this question. But I think it can be simple to put on the page.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

are you using JS to connect and query the database?? 
normally you set something to destroy a session.. to keep him logged in don't destroy it... simple?

e.g.
in php:

```
session_destroy();
```

destorys the session... you could do:

```
if(keep_logged) #the person checked the stay logged in box
{
  $_SESSION['stayalive']=true;
}
```

session terminators:

```
if($_SESSION['keepalive'] == false && inactive_time > 1hour) session_destroy();
```

the thing is you have to terminate the sessions and destroy them.. this is set in the logout page.. but what happens if he does not log out (closes browser)? you stay logged in ***until cookie expires***(set in server config),

so what devs do is set a function that would check last action's time and current action's time and see the differnce.. some set the min inactive for the session_destory() to work to 1 hour.. some more and some less... you just need to crate a bypass condition

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is using javascript's **localStorage** or **cookies**.

### **LocalStorage**

With local storage, web applications can store data locally within the user's browser.

Before HTML5, application data had to be stored in cookies, included in every server request. Local storage is more secure, and large amounts of data can be stored locally, without affecting website performance.

Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server.

Local storage is per domain. All pages, from one domain, can store and access the same data.

**Link to help you get started :** http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

### **Cookies**

Cookies are data, stored in small text files, on your computer.

When a web server has sent a web page to a browser, the connection is shut down, and the server forgets everything about the user.

Cookies were invented to solve the problem "how to remember information about the user":

When a user visits a web page, his name can be stored in a cookie.
Next time the user visits the page, the cookie "remembers" his name.

**Link to help you get started :** http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you need to clear this code.and for this you first need to add jquery library into your html code.

```
$("#lembrar").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        // CODE FOR REMEMBERING DATA FOR FUTURE LOGINS
    }
});
```

Now,for storing user data on client side,you can use 2 javascript function.

```
// cname  - name in which you want to store your user data
// cvalue - value of that userdata
// exdays - expire in how much days
// ex: setCookie('user','jay',1)
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

// cname - name in which you store your user value
// ex : getCookie('user')  -->  'jay' as output
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Note : store user data by cookies is browser dependent.if user manually delete all cookies of browser than there is no meaning of expiry date.

Comment: Found this code in a similar question. I've copied to my JS file for tests:
$("#login").submit(function() {
        if ($('#remember').is(':checked')) {
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var pass = $('#pass').val();
            $.cookie('email', email, { expires: 14 });
            $.cookie('pass', pass, { expires: 14 });
            $.cookie('remember', true, { expires: 14 });
        }
        else
        {
            $.cookie('email', null);
            $.cookie('pass', null);
            $.cookie('remember', null);
        }
  });
});